# Can I use "that how" in "it is important that how people do that"?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say:
It is important ***that how*** people do that?
In other words, can I use "that" and "how" together?

Comment: No, that's not correct. You can say *It's important that people do that*, or you can say *It's important how people do that*. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Thanks. It was just something I heard which made me confused.

Comment: You might have heard them say "It's important that's how people do that", meaning people should do it in the way indicated. It's a very clumsy way of saying something, but clumsy stuff crops up all the time in everyday speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not grammatical, and I'm actually not sure what idea you're trying to communicate here. I'm trying to fill in the blank in "It is important _____ people do that" and I can't find a good fit. I would need more context to find appropriate phrasing.

Comment: Thanks, I heard someone say this which made me curious! Though I knew this could not be correct...